# How to replace a specific sub-string amongst all the string in bash?

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have two strings/paths in different lines of a file as per the below,

```
    cmd a/b/c -x -y


    cmd a/b/c -x
```

Amongst the two strings, I want to replace only the second string. I have used `sed` to replace the second string but due to an error in my command, I am replacing both the strings.
Please let me know on the usage of `sed` or any other command in bash to perform this operation.

Comment: If John1024’s answer works for you, then you got lucky, because I find your question very hard to understand. Please try to make it clearer. Are you talking about one line of input that begins with `(1). ⁠`? Or are you talking about two strings that might occur on the same line, but might occur on different lines? And will they be *exactly* as you show them, or is there any possibility of variation (e.g., could it actually be `command p/q/r -x -y`? or `cmd a/b/c -x -z`)? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And what do you mean when you say “replace both the strings”?  — you just said that you want to replace only one of the two strings. … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed doesn't have some of the nice look-ahead features that other regex engines support but we can still do what you want.  Try:

```
sed 's@cmd a/b/c -x -y@\n@g; s@cmd a/b/c -x@New String@g; s@\n@cmd a/b/c -x -y@'
```

#### Example

```
$ cat file
(1). cmd a/b/c -x -y (2). cmd a/b/c -x
$ sed 's@cmd a/b/c -x -y@\n@g; s@cmd a/b/c -x@New String@g; s@\n@cmd a/b/c -x -y@' file
(1). cmd a/b/c -x -y (2). New String
```

#### How it works

- `s@cmd a/b/c -x -y@\n@g`

  This replaces the string that you don't want with a newline.
- `s@cmd a/b/c -x@New String@g`

  This does the substitution that you want.
- `s@\n@cmd a/b/c -x -y@`

  This restores the string that you wanted unchanged.

#### Using variables

One can use variables with sed but it is fraught with problems including both errors, surprise results, and even security violations.  awk is much better at handling variables easily and safely.

First, let's create the shell variables:

```
keep='cmd a/b/c -x -y'
target='cmd a/b/c -x'
new='New String'
```

Now, let's run an awk command:

```
$ awk -v k="$keep" -v t="$target" -v n="$new" '{gsub(k, "\n"); gsub(t, n); gsub(/\n/, k)} 1' file
(1). cmd a/b/c -x -y (2). New String
```

The logic for the awk command is exactly the same as for sed.

How it works:

- `-v k="$keep" -v t="$target" -v n="$new"`

  These options use shell variables `keep`, `target`, and `new` to define , respectively, awk variables `k`, `t`, and `n`.

  Note that `k` and `t` will be treated as regular expressions.  If they contain any regex active characters, such as `+` or `*`, they should be escaped with backslashes.
- `gsub(k, "\n")`

  This replaces all occurrences of `k` with a newline.
- `gsub(t, n)`

  This replaces all occurrences of target string `t` with the new string `n`.
- `gsub(/\n/, k)`

  This restores the strings `k`.
- `1`

  This tells awk to print the line.

Comment: Can we replace strings (1), (2) and New String with a variables & will it still work?

Comment: Yes but, if you want to use variables, I strongly recommend that you switch to awk.  See updated answer for awk code.